# Possible ways to do eval

Tags: javascript

The ones that I'm aware of are `eval`, `Function` and `setTimeout`. Even though [`setImmediate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate) reference doesn't mention that it can be called with string argument, I assume it will work the same way as `setTimeout`in this regard.

What are the possible ways (including non-standard ones) to evaluate the code from a string in browsers?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  This question seems too broad as it is.  It's just asking for a list.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess it is. There's a bunch of ways how this can be done in Node, and this isn't that important since there's no focus on security there in this regard.

Comment: @zero298 As you said, I'm asking for a list. There is no particular coding problem I'm trying to solve. The question isn't too broad because it contains enough details to get a quality answer. The reason why I asked it is if that I had to list these methods for some reason (basic security in DSL language, code review rules, etc), I would possibly fail to name them all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On browsers, the only ones I know are:

- `eval`
- The `Function` constructor
- `setTimeout` and related (`setInterval`, non-standard `setImmediate`)
- Creating a script element, setting its text content, and appending it to the document (either via DOM methods, or using `document.write` or similar)
- Using the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol on links and such (and then either clicking them artifically or inviting the user to do so)

  - Bookmarklets are a special case of this one
- DOM0 event handlers (and then either triggering them artificially or inviting the user to do so) *(nice one [GOTO 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297097/possible-ways-to-do-eval#comment87611432_50297139))*

Live:

```js
eval("console.log('eval');");
(0,eval)("console.log('indirect eval');");

new Function("console.log('Function constructor');")();

setTimeout("console.log('setTimeout and such');", 0);

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "console.log('script element');";
document.body.appendChild(script);

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "javascript:console.log('javascript: pseudo-protocol');";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("onclick", "console.log('DOM0 event handler');");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.click();
/* Or to be long-winded
div.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {
  view: window,
  bubbles: true,
  cancelable: true
}));
*/
```

Comment: Template literals, embedded code in DOM event handlers e.g. `onlick='alert("Hello")'`, etc.

Comment: @GOTO0 - Gah, I missed that out. I'll add it. (Template literals really aren't here or there, but `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers are.)

Answer (score 2):

non-standard one using immediate execution

```
<h1>

</h1>
<script></script>

$("script").html("(function(){$('h1').html('wow');})()");
```

There is also a non-standard way not mentioned so far here that is using wkhtmltopdf, in this way wkhtmltopdf myjscode.html all.pdf where myjscode.html is generated with fopen/cat or something taking string as argument. When pdf is executed, javascript is executed (https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf), also javascript is executed server side (yes). This could seems non relevant but it has big implications on security. If we're going do a pdf based in part on user inputs with wkhtmltopdf we have this problem to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks. While such methods likely use internally the ones that were already listed, it's worthwhile to mention them.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the methods mentioned in the other answers, in a browser you could do:

```
document.write('<script>doSomething()</script>');
```

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'data:text/javascript,' + encodeURIComponent('doSomething()');
document.body.appendChild(script);
```